# Get value in 1-to-many relationship (EF Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm seeking an equivalent to this SQL query in EF Core:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (Select AdminRoleId From EventAdmins Where EventId = Events.Id And AdminId = [value from cookie]) As EventRoleId From Events
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public IList<Event> Events { get; set; }
public IList<EventAdmin> EventAdmins { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {

    var adminId = Guid.Parse(Request.Cookies["Adm_AdminId"]);

    Events = await _context.Events.SelectMany(e => e.EventAdmins.Where(x => x.EventId == e.Id && x.AdminId == adminId).Select(x => x.AdminRoleId)).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

    return Page();
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, but I get an error saying "Error CS0452: The type 'Guid' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method".

Event model:

```
public class Event {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public IList<EventAdmin> EventAdmins { get; set; }

}
```

EventAdmin model:

```
public class EventAdmin {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public Guid AdminId { get; set; }
    public Guid AdminRoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public Event Events { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Where is `TEntity` in the code? Problem lies on that!

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: Look at the error message. Its excepting `TEntity` to be reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reason

This error occurs because you're trying to ask EF Core not to track a list of `GUID`. However, the list of Guid is a list of value types.

As you know, EF Core can only track a series of reference type, so the [method signature of `AsNoTracking<TEntity>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-2.1) is :

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> AsNoTracking<TEntity> (this IQueryable<TEntity> source) 
    where TEntity : class;
```

Note the  constraints of **`where TEntity : class`**.

In other words, **you can never invoke `AsNoTracking<Guid>()`**:

```
Events = await _context.Events
    .SelectMany(e => e.EventAdmins.Where(x => x.EventId == e.Id).Select(x => x.AdminRoleId))
    .AsNoTracking()    // Actually, it will invoke `AsNoTracking<Guid>()`
    .ToListAsync();
```

#### How to Fix

Your SQL doesn't seem valid. I guess you want to return a `{Id, Name, EventRoleId}`.

If you would like to do that with `SelectMany`, you could simply query as below:

```
var Events = await this._context.Events
    .SelectMany( 
        e => e.EventAdmins.Where(x => x.EventId == e.Id).Select(x => x.AdminRoleId),
        (p,g) => new {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            EventRoleId = g
        }
    )
    // .AsNoTracking()   
    .ToListAsync();
```

**There's no need to call `.AsNoTracking()` at all**. Because **no tracking is performed if the result set does not contain any entity types**.

---

As a side note, you shouldn't decorate the `Event.EventAdmins` with a `[ForeignKey("Id")]` attribute :

```
    public class Event {

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public IList EventAdmins { get; set; }

    }
```

Because the `Event` is the principal entity and the `EventAdmin` is the dependent entity. Only the `EventAdmin` has a foreign key that references the `Event`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation! I actually tried something very similar at first, but then I get (also with your code) an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:System.Guid Id, string Name, System.Guid EventRoleId>> to System.Collections.Generic.IList<VPV.Models.Event>"? I've edited the question a little because I left out the "adminId" in the example.

Comment: @Mads If you want to return a list of IList<VPV.Models.Event> why did you want a property of ` EventRoleId` ? There's no such a property within `Event` at all

Comment: I just want AdminRoleId from EventAdmins where EventAdmins.EventId = Events.Id and EventAdmins.AdminId = adminId. I don't know why I get that error? If I do "var events = _context..." the error goes away, but shouldn't it be "Events = _context..." where Events is referring to "public IList<Event> Events { get; set; }" ?

Comment: @Mads Firstly, in your code above, your wrote `Events = await _context.Events.SelectMany(e => e.EventAdmins.Where(x => x.EventId == e.Id && x.AdminId == adminId).Select(x => x.AdminRoleId)).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();` , here the left side is  `Events`, and the right side is  `IList<Guid>` . It make no sense. So in my code , I change the code to declare a new variable `Events` by `var Events=....`

Comment: @Mads Secondly, If you want to return a type of `IList<Event>`, there's no need to use `SelectMany()`, because the `SelectMany()` will flatten the `List of List`.

Comment: I you look at the SQL example in the question, you can see what I want. I want af list of events, and if the admin logged in has a match in EventAdmins, it should return that AdminRoleId, otherwise null. The reason why I do it like that (instead of doing _context.EventAdmins.Include(e => e.Events).Where(a => a.AdminId == adminId) is that if the admin logged in has a specific userrole, the events should be selectable (without a role) anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185344/discussion-between-itminus-and-mads).

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query doesn't seem to include adminId so I can't see how it could work. Try something like this:

```
var eventAdmin = _context.EventAdmin.SingleOrDefault( e => e.Id == adminId);

var events = eventAdmin.Events;
```

Try using a tool like Linqpad to dissect your queries one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you. If I get your answer correctly you're first filtering the EventAdmins by adminId (as I forgot in my example - edited). Then I could also do _context.EventAdmins.Include(e => e.Events)... but I must have all the events, and if the admin logged in has no match in EventAdmins, the AdminRoleId should just be null.

Comment: Without some working code it's quite hard to answer your question. May I suggest you get Linqpad (https://www.linqpad.net/) and try doing your query one step at a time. It'll create a quick class that is very close to EFCORE automatically or if you have the dll for your classes you can use that too. The app is free (it's a small fee if you want intellisense).